# JQuery UI: How to pass values to dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, jquery-ui-dialog

I am very new to JQuery UI.
I am facing issue while loading modal dialog window using JQuery.
Here I am trying simple example that will open dialog and will load a new page on onClick event of radio button.
The new page thats getting loaded in to dialog is dynamic page which takes some values from database based on user in put provided through text box of main page.

I am not sure how to pass the value
    of text box from main page?    Alsosd
    I tried to pass the value of text
    box by appending url attributes to
    url.. but no luck:(. i.e. my url is
    regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action
    and I am trying to pass it as 
    regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action*?consumer*
    where consumer is value from text
    box.Is this the right way?
Provinding code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>



<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "css/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
        </style>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $("#CUSTOM").click( showDialog );
            //variable to reference window
            myWindow = $('#dialog');

            }
        );     
        //function to show dialog        
        var showDialog = function() {         
            //instantiate the dialog

            myWindow.load("regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action?consumer").dialog({ height: 350,
                            width: 400,
                            modal: true,
                            position: 'center',
                            autoOpen:false,
                            title:'Hello World',
                            overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
            });

            //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this         
            myWindow.show();          
            //open the dialog
            myWindow.dialog("open");
            }      
        //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog     
        var closeDialog = function() {
            myWindow.dialog("close");
            }
    </script>

  <script>




  function setSession()
  {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog").load("regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action?as").dialog({ modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false, width: 515, height: 245 });
      });

      $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
 <div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="submittedMetadataSelection" id="DEFAULT" value="DEFAULT" checked/>
                                        <label for="DEFAULT">DEFAULT</label>

                                        <input type="radio" name="submittedMetadataSelection" id="CUSTOM" value="CUSTOM" "/>
                                        <label for="CUSTOM">CUSTOM</label>

</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Struts2-jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) may help simplify this for you and save you from having to write a lot of jQuery code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "load", try to use the $.ajax method and send the parameters with "data" object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action",
    data: ({customer: "John"}),
    traditional: true,
    success: function(loadedData) {
        // assuming that the contents of loadedData is html
        myWindow.html(loadedData);
        myWindow.dialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 that's what I do... where avitor put _url: "regressionTestCustomMetadataSelection.action"_ I like to use the s:url tag which writes out the full url correctly.

Comment: The jQuery ajax call will not work with struts2 by default unless you also add, "traditional: true,", could you add this to your answer?